# Find $(P,\Psi)$ such that $\alpha P\geqslant \Psi^TP\Psi\geqslant \beta P$

Tags: convex-optimization, control-theory, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

Given constants $\alpha\geq \beta>0$, find a nonsingular matrix $\Psi\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a postive definite matrix $P$ such that
$$
    \begin{aligned}
        \alpha P\geqslant \Psi^TP\Psi&\geqslant \beta P\\
    \end{aligned}
$$
It is preferred that the method devised to find $\Psi,P$ is based on LMI, cone complentarity linearization or BMI or SDP programming. Here $\geq$ means "positive semidefinite" for matrices. Any help is appreciated!

And, there is an extended question about this problem, what kind of property should $\Psi$ be with such that $\alpha P\geq \Psi^TP\Psi\geq \beta P$ holds for all positive semidefinite $P$?

Comment: What about $$\Psi=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}} I$$

Comment: Clearly, this $\Psi$ is OK. But I am wondering if there are some other kinds of $\Psi$ except identity matrix, or more generally, what properties should $\Psi$ be with such that $\alpha P\geq \Psi^TP\Psi\geq \beta P$.

Comment: You mean for example in the case one already have other LMI's and want to incorporate these inequalities as well?

Comment: Yes,  you are right, @Kwin van der Been.